# Can the memory management of a property change if it's redefined in a class extension?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, declared-property

If I have a property like this:

```
//test.h

@interface test
@property (nonatomic, readonly, weak) NSObject x;
@end
```

redefined in the implementation file to be read/write:

```
// test.m
@interface test ()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSObject x;
@end
```

I used weak in .h, but I said nothing in the extension, will the property keep the 'weak' specifier, or will it change to 'strong'?

Will the keywords strong/assign/weak be overwritten when the property is redefined?

Comment: As a common practice I always specify the `strong/weak/assign` attribute of the property in the class extension. It's not needed in the read-only public declaration.

Comment: @rmaddy - Declaring just `readonly` in the `.h` and `readwrite, weak` in the class extension in the `.m` gives "Primary property declaration is implicitly strong while redeclaration in class extension is weak" under Xcode 5.1.1. However including `strong` or `assign` in the extension does not raise the ire of the compiler. Has a later compiler changed this?

Comment: @CRD Hmmm. I guess I haven't done that with `weak` properties. Good to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple test with Xcode 5.1.1 shows the `weak` attribute is kept. The same is true for the `assign` and `strong` attributes - you can specify them in the `.h` and omit them in the `.m`, if you do include them in the `.m` the two must match.

**Having said that, I do not know if this is documented anywhere. But then the semantics of Objective-C are not formally defined anywhere either. So use at your own risk.**

Recommendation: just repeat it.

Comment: how you check if the attribute is set? I am trying to find a way to check these things. Thanks!

Comment: At compile time just read the `.h`; for runtime lookup the function `property_getAttributes` in the documentation.